# Or operator in spring specification not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to search on a view using spring specification but can't make the or operator work.

Here is my entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Immutable
public class EntityA {
    @Id
    @GeneratorValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integerid;
  
    private String content;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private EntityB entityB;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private EntityC entityC;
}
```

My method

```
Page<EntityA> page = repository.findAll(EntityARepository.specification(id), pageable);
```

My specification method inside EntityARepository

```
static Specification<EntityA> specification(int id) {
    return (tx, cq, cb} -> {
    Predicate predicateB = cb.equals(tx.get("entityB").get("id"), id);
    Predicate predicateC = cb.equals(tx.get("entityC").get("id"), id);

    List<Predicate> predicates = Lists.of(predicateB, predicateC);

    return cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
}
```

I also tried to write 2 seperate specification methods and combine them with `Specification.where(specB).or(specC);` but it is not working either.

However it is working fine when i use basic Spring Data Jpa methode `FindAllByEntityBIdOrEntityCId(int idB, int idC)`

I can't figure out what i am doing wrong. I am getting an empty result.

Comment: what happens when you use spring.jpa.show-sql=true (application.properties)?

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with `toArray(new Predicate[0])` method call.

As number of predicates are two you should create a predicate array of size two as shown below:

```
cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[2]));
```

Also, your method contains many syntax errors. Please try below method:

```
public static Specification<EntityA> specification(final int id) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        Predicate predicateB = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.<EntityB>get("entityB").<Integer>get("id"), id);
        Predicate predicateC = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.<EntityC>get("entityC").<Integer>get("id"), id);

        List<Predicate> predicates = Arrays.asList(predicateB, predicateC);

        return criteriaBuilder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    };
}
```

Comment: This is not working. i tried `toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])`

Comment: Also, I can see there are many syntax errors in your code. You should use ```equal()``` method of ```CriteriaBuilder``` instead of ```equals()```. Could you please try the method I have updated in the answer?

Comment: Not working. EntityA is mapping a database view and not a table. Does it matter ?